# alert box not happening on window.unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why doesn't the following code cause an alert box when the user navigates away from the page? I tested in Chrome and no alert boxes occurs (and they aren't being blocked). I also tried it in FireFox and Internet Explorer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).unload(function() {
        alert("bye");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

According to [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUiP7ylzTYc&t=2m8s) it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
   return 'Bye';
});
```

Or try using plain JavaScript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   return 'bye';
}
```

Chrome blocks alerts onunload.

Answer (score -1):

In html script

```
      window.beforeonunload = function(){
      return 'bye';
       }
```

use the above code you may get your answer